# how to use sequelize.fn(['if'])?

Tags: sequelize.js

for example：Executed (default):

```
SELECT if(`evaluates`.`all`, 'good','notgood') AS `sign`, count(*) AS `count` FROM `evaluates` AS `evaluates` WHERE `evaluates`.`deleted_at` IS NULL GROUP BY `sign`;

await DBC.evaluates.count({
        attributes: [[DBC.sequelize.fn(['if'],
        DBC.sequelize.col("`evaluates`.`all`"), ["good", "notgood"]), 'sign']],
        group: ["sign"]
    });
```

but Executed (default):

```
 SELECT if(`evaluates`.`all` > 3, 'good','notgood') AS `sign`, count(*) AS `count` FROM `evaluates` AS `evaluates` WHERE `evaluates`.`deleted_at` IS NULL GROUP BY `sign`;
```

how?

```
await DBC.evaluates.count({
        attributes: [[DBC.sequelize.fn(['if'], DBC.sequelize.col("`evaluates`.`all` > 3"), ["good", "notgood"]), 'sign']],
        group: ["sign"]
    });?
```

it's false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

literal("`evaluates`.`all` > 3")

Comment: it's just give `true` or `false` result,, :(